# Avoid PHP notice when destructuring array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say we have an array, and we try to get the value of a key which does not exist:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b'];
$val0 = $arr[0] ?? null;
$val1 = $arr[1] ?? null;
$val2 = $arr[2] ?? null;
```

Because of the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), this will not emit any notices, regardless of whether the array elements exist.

---

In PHP7.1 [symmetric array destructuring](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring) was introduced; it is helpful, but this code:

```
[$val0, $val1, $val2] = $arr;
```

will emit an `Undefined index: 2 in $arr ...` notice.

Is it possible to destructure the array while avoiding these notices?

Comment: If you know what keys the array should have why not merge them before doing anything else?

`$ourArray = array_merge(['a' => null, 'b' => null, 'c' => null], $ourArray);`

Comment: Your example of array destructing doesn't make sense...

Comment: @JonStirling could you tell me please why it doesnt make any sense?

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention this style of destructuring. Why do you think it should be possible like this, using dictionary "flavor" of the arrays on the receiving side?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It seems to be [OK syntax](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/posts/2017/the-list-function-and-practical-uses-of-array-destructuring-in-php) - [*link to the RFC*](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/list_keys)

Comment: @h2ooooooo: ah, so one misses just the keyword `list` here?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, the keyword "list" is the oldschool way of doing it, kinda like doing `$foo = array(1, 2, 3);` instead of `$foo = [1, 2, 3];` [the code works fine but his code is complaining that the c key is not defined](https://3v4l.org/3M82J) (notice how the first one throws a notice?)

Comment: @h2ooooooo: got it, thanks. In ruby, this would have worked just fine: `a, b, c = ourArray.values_at('a', 'b', 'c')`, where `c` would be nil. Maybe similar api exists here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Using the error suppression operator that Michas mentioned is probably the easiest way without doing merging of the array or filling with NULL. I wasn't aware of this new syntax either. Personally I'd probably go for a different solution all together.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `@` operator.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

```
@[$val0, $val1, $val2] = $arr;
```

**Disclaimer**
This operator is controversial. It may hide useful errors messages from function calls. A lot of programmers will avoid it even for hight cost. For assignments it is safe though.

---

*Based on comment by h2ooooooo.*

If you are able to define defaults for all your values, you can use code below.

```
[$val0, $val1, $val2] = $arr + $defaults;
```

The operator `+` is important. The function `array_merge` will not preserve numeric keys.

The definition for `$defaults` may look like this:

```
$defaults = array_fill(0, 3, null);
```

Or you can manually define values for every possible key.

Comment: No clue who downvoted you (probably just for hiding errors in general). [This answer works](https://3v4l.org/Vhg6I).

Comment: Many developers discourage the "stfu operator".  Yes, it works, but it generally indicates a hacky solution that should be replaced by something more appropriate (I didn't downvote).

Comment: I would also accept @h2ooooooo solution: `$ourArray = array_merge(['a' => null, 'b' => null, 'c' => null], $ourArray);`

Comment: You can simplify the $defaults definition by doing something like [`$defaults = array_fill_keys(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], null);`](https://eval.in/957671)

Comment: Neither of these solutions work on a `foreach` statement, unfortunately.

Comment: The option to have defaults is a perfect solution for destructuring an `explode($separator, $string)` when you have determined -as a developer decision- the number of possibilities that will come out from and that you will use.

Answer (score 14):

You could try ensuring the key exists in the array, by merging some defaults:

```
[$val0, $val1, $val2] = $arr + [2 => null];
```